# QXmlQuery and XSLT20: Resultant Output String is empty everytime, works well on shell(xmlpattern)

Tags: qt, xslt-2.0, qtxml

I am writing a class to parse Itunes Libray File using QXmlQuery and QT-XSLT.

Here's my sample code:

```
ItunesLibParser::ItunesLibParser()
{
    pathToLib = QString("/Users/rakesh/temp/itunes_xslt/itunes_music_library.xml");
}

void ItunesLibParser::createXSLFile(QFile &inFile)
{
    if (inFile.exists()) {
        inFile.remove();
    }

    inFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QTextStream out(&inFile);

    out << QString("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>");
    out << QString("<xsl:stylesheet version=\"2.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\">");
    out << QString("<xsl:output method=\"text\" />");


    out << QString("<xsl:template name=\"playlistNames\">");
    out << QString("<xsl:value-of select=\"child::integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Playlist ID']\"/>");
    out << QString("<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>");
    out << QString("<xsl:value-of select=\"child::string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Name']\"/>");
    out << QString("<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>");
    out << QString("</xsl:template>");


    out << QString("<xsl:template match=\"/\">");
    out << QString("<xsl:for-each select=\"plist/dict/array/dict\">");
    out << QString("<xsl:call-template name=\"playlistNames\"/>");
    out << QString("</xsl:for-each>");
    out << QString("</xsl:template>");

    out << QString("</xsl:stylesheet>");

    inFile.close();

    return;

}

void ItunesLibParser::dumpPlayList()
{

    QXmlQuery query(QXmlQuery::XSLT20);
    query.setFocus(QUrl(pathToLib));

    QFile xslFile("plist.xsl");
    createXSLFile(xslFile);

    query.setQuery(QUrl("plist.xsl"));

    QStringList* outDump = new QStringList();

    query.evaluateTo(outDump);


    if(outDump != NULL) {

        QStringList::iterator iter = (*outDump).begin();
        for (; iter != (*outDump).end();
               ++iter)
            //code flow doesn't come here. It means being() == end()
            std::cout << (*iter).toLocal8Bit().constData() << std::endl;
    }

    return;
}
```

OutDump here doesn't contain data. While in Shell (xmlpatterns-4.7 mystlye.xsl itunes_music_library.xml ), If I run my Query I get proper output.

Is there anything, wrong I am doing while calling it programatically? I checked out plist.xsl is created properly, but my doubt is whether "/Users/rakesh/temp/itunes_xslt/itunes_music_library.xml" this is getting loaded or not? Or there might be another reasons, I am confused. Is there any experts to throw some light onto problem, I will be glad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intead from reading from the file, I read the file into buffer and converted that int string as passed to setquery. That solved the problem.

Here's sample code for those who could face similar problem in future.

```
void ITunesMlibParser::parsePlayListItemXml(int plistId)
{

    QXmlQuery xQuery(QXmlQuery::XSLT20);
    QFile inFile("/Users/rakesh/temp/itunes_xslt/itunes_music_library.xml");

    if (!inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        return;
    }

    QByteArray bArray;
    while (!inFile.atEnd()) {
        bArray += inFile.readLine();
    }

    QBuffer xOriginalContent(&bArray);
    xOriginalContent.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);
    xOriginalContent.reset();


    if (xQuery.setFocus(&xOriginalContent))
         std::cout << "File Loaded" << std::endl;

//.. 
//..

}
```

Thanks
Rakesh